# Major Concurrency Issue

Tags: java, list, concurrency

I have looked around but I cannot find a decent answer to the issue that I am having. I have a list that is constantly being modified and read from but I keep getting concurrency issues. Note: There are 2 threads that constantly pull data from this list.
The issues pop up on `doEntityTick()` and `getEntity()`. Note: `doEntityTick` issues are caused by me adding an entity to the list.

World:

```
package UnNamedRpg.World;

import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;

import UnNamedRpg.Player.Game.GameManager;
import UnNamedRpg.World.Entity.Entity;
import UnNamedRpg.World.Entity.EntityCharacter;
import UnNamedRpg.World.Entity.EntityLiving;
import UnNamedRpg.World.Entity.EntityProjectile;


public class World {

    private String name;
    private ArrayList<Boundary> boundList = new ArrayList<Boundary>();
    private Collection<Entity> entityList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Entity>());

    public World(String name){
        setName(name);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public ArrayList<Entity> getEntityList(){
        ArrayList<Entity> newList = new ArrayList<Entity>();
        synchronized(entityList) {
            Iterator<Entity> iter = entityList.iterator();
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                Entity ent = iter.next();
                newList.add(ent);
            }
        }
        return newList;
    }

    public ArrayList<Entity> getEntityAtCoordinatePair(double x, double y){
        ArrayList<Entity> tempList = new ArrayList<Entity>();
        for(Entity ent : getEntityList()){
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle((int)ent.getX(), (int)ent.getY(), ent.getWidth(), ent.getHeight());
            if(rect.contains(x, y)){
                tempList.add(ent);
            }
        }
        return tempList;
    }

    public void addEntity(Entity ent){
        synchronized(entityList){
            entityList.add(ent);
            if(ent.getID() == -1){
                ent.setID(entityList.size());
            }
        }
    }

    public Entity getEntity(int id){
        synchronized(entityList) {
              Iterator<Entity> i = entityList.iterator();
              while (i.hasNext()){
                  Entity ent = i.next();
                  if(ent.getID() == id){
                      return ent;
                  }
              }

          }
        return null;
    }

    public void doEntityTick(){
        synchronized(entityList) {
            Iterator<Entity> iter = entityList.iterator();

            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                Entity ent = iter.next();
                if(ent instanceof EntityLiving){
                    EntityLiving entLiv = (EntityLiving)ent;
                    if(entLiv.getHealth() <= 0){
                        entLiv.setDead();
                    }
                    if(entLiv.isDead() && entLiv.getHealth() > 0){
                        GameManager.isSpawning = true;
                    }
                    entLiv.doEntityTick();
                }
                if(ent instanceof EntityProjectile){
                    EntityProjectile entProj = (EntityProjectile)ent;
                    entProj.doTick();
                    entProj.setCurrentRange(entProj.getCurrentRange() + 1);
                    if(entProj.getCurrentRange() >= entProj.getRange()){
                        entProj.setDead();
                    }
                }

                if(ent.isDead() && !(ent instanceof EntityCharacter)){
                    iter.remove();
                }
            }
        }   
    }

    public void addBounds(Boundary bounds){
        boundList.add(bounds);
    }

    public int getBoundsID(int x, int y){
        for(int i=0;i<boundList.size();i++){
            if(boundList.get(i).contains(x, y))
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public int getBoundsID(Boundary bounds){
        for(int i=0;i<boundList.size();i++){
            if(boundList.get(i) == bounds)
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public void removeBounds(Boundary bounds){
        boundList.remove(bounds);
    }

    public Boundary getBounds(int x, int y){
        for(Boundary bounds : boundList){
            if(bounds.contains(x, y)){
                return bounds;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public boolean isInBounds(int posX, int posY){
        for(Boundary bounds : boundList){
            if(bounds.contains(posX, posY)){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Stack Trace:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)
    at UnNamedRpg.World.World.doEntityTick(World.java:83)
    at UnNamedRpg.Player.Game.GameManager$1.run(GameManager.java:49)
```

Comment: And what kind of concurrency issue you have?

Comment: Why aren't you synchronizing around the iteration in `getEntityList()`?

Comment: @RealSkeptic Changed that but the issue still persits.

Comment: @Tsyvarev What do you mean what kind? I am trying to add to the list if that helps.

Comment: You are saying you have "issues" but you do not explain what those issues are. You just have comments that say "issues here", "issues here". What issues? Do you have a deadlock? A race condition? An exception? Bad performance? What is happening and what do you expect to happen instead?

Comment: @RealSkeptic Honestly i'm not sure other than when I attempt to add to the list it throws a concurrency exception pointing to the commented line of code on doEntityTick() in the world class.

Comment: Well? That's exactly what I was asking about. Please copy the error including the stack trace to your question, properly formatted. This is *essential* information. If the error occurs in more than one place, then add both stack traces. While you are editing your question, please update to your latest code (you said that you added the synchronization in `getEntityList()` - so your latest code and the freshest stack traces.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I've added the stack trace but it really isn't descriptive at all. NOTE: This only happens when I add the entity to the world that spawns the projectile. The entity tick is found above where the work is actually done, this is the only part that varies from the other classes of the same type.

Comment: Are you sure that it's actually an issue with multi-threading? It is possible to get this error when a single list is modified inconsistently by a single thread. From docs: "Note that this exception does not always indicate that an object has been concurrently modified by a *different* thread. If a single thread issues a sequence of method invocations that violates the contract of an object, the object may throw this exception. For example, if a thread modifies a collection directly while it is iterating over the collection with a fail-fast iterator, the iterator will throw this exception."

Comment: @Brick It honestly could be just one thread, I was just trying to get the point across that there ARE multiple threads interacting with it. If it were the single-thread issue then how would I go about fixing this? All of the code in the world class is called by one thread.

Comment: You have two methods named `doEntityTick()`.  Copy/paste mistake or do both `World` and `Entity` have one?

Comment: In the snippet of World.java you provided, which line is #83?

Comment: @JoeCoder                 Entity ent = iter.next();
on doEntityTick()

Comment: Unrelated to the `ConcurrentModificationException`, but the body of `World::addEntity()` should be made atomic by synchronizing on the `entityList` (or the list size might be unexpected value) even though your tick value makes this improbable.

Comment: @JoeCoder Whoops, I just added that and it didn't change anything. I honestly have no idea what would be causing this.

Comment: You have rendered your question completely off-topic. Please read the [help/on-topic]: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.* It took a long time to get the "specific problem and error" from you, and now you have removed the code from the question. Please edit it to conform to the rules. If the code is too long prepare a [mcve] instead.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I have NOT removed the code, I have simply given you a link to the entire repository instead so that (if wished) you could view the rest of the code and see if there was an issue there. Not to mention that this repository is updated with the most recent code so that I don't have to continually edit it on here.

Comment: As I said, the site rules require the code to be *in the question itself* - not a link. I did not invent that rule, it's in the [help/on-topic].

Comment: @RealSkeptic well sorry but I assumed that having all of the code posted would help. I'll add it back when I get home. Now enough about rules, do you have any idea what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after an entire day of looking at the code I managed to find a fix. Instead of having the entities spawn immediately it will instead stick them into a queue and await the next world tick in order to spawn them. I thank everyone who attempted to help and have given those a +1 who have helped me come across this answer.